# How to test Symfony2 models using PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I've been trying to test a model in a Symfony2 project, but I don't know how to get the entity manager to save and retrive records.

Can anyone point me to the right docs for this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to test your models, you can use setUp() method. [link to docs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html)

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class MyModelTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $_em;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $kernel = static::createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();
        $this->_em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $this->_em->beginTransaction();
    }

    /**
     * Rollback changes.
     */
    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->_em->rollback();
    }

    public function testSomething()
    {
        $user = $this->_em->getRepository('MyAppMyBundle:MyModel')->find(1);
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: And here's a link to the docs @symfony.com - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html

Answer (score 7):

Symfony2 models are expected to be domain objects that represent [domain models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) in the code.

> domain objects should be defined purely to implement the business
>   behavior of the corresponding domain concept, rather than be defined
>   by the requirements of a more specific technology framework. -- [Domain-driven design - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)

Domain objects (and its tests) should not depend on Symfony2 APIs and Doctrine APIs except if you really want to test themselves.

> Writing Symfony2 unit tests is no different than writing standard PHPUnit unit tests. -- [Symfony - Testing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html)

You can test business logic (processes, rules, behaviors, etc.) represented in domain objects with PHPUnit (or Behat) and usually [test doubles](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/test-doubles.html).

Comment: Yes, I have read the docs and understand those concepts. But if i want to test, for example, the Sluggable behavior, it only works after the record is saved. How can I test that? nevermind that the bundle is probably tested, I just want to see how to test things in symfony2

Comment: It is important for us to know what the core concerns of the product are.

If you are developing the Sluggable behavior, it is the most important thing for you that the slug string is correctly generated based on the values of the sluggable fields, and so you shoud test it. Of course you can test whether or not the value of the slug field is stored properly into the database, but it is not a core concern of the product, and it is a core concern of Doctrine itself (and it is already tested).

Comment: Yes, but the slug is created aftersave, so in order to test if the generated string is ok, i *need* to save the object, not to test the save itself (which of course is very tested by Doctrine team), but to check the generated string, which is a concern of the system.

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace Ibw\JobeetBundle\Tests\Repository;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\DropDatabaseDoctrineCommand;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\CreateDatabaseDoctrineCommand;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\CreateSchemaDoctrineCommand;

class CategoryRepositoryTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $em;
    private $application;

    public function setUp()
    {
        static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
        static::$kernel->boot();

        $this->application = new Application(static::$kernel);

        // drop the database
        $command = new DropDatabaseDoctrineCommand();
        $this->application->add($command);
        $input = new ArrayInput(array(
            'command' => 'doctrine:database:drop',
            '--force' => true
        ));
        $command->run($input, new NullOutput());

        // we have to close the connection after dropping the database so we don't get "No database selected" error
        $connection = $this->application->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getConnection();
        if ($connection->isConnected()) {
            $connection->close();
        }

        // create the database
        $command = new CreateDatabaseDoctrineCommand();
        $this->application->add($command);
        $input = new ArrayInput(array(
            'command' => 'doctrine:database:create',
        ));
        $command->run($input, new NullOutput());

        // create schema
        $command = new CreateSchemaDoctrineCommand();
        $this->application->add($command);
        $input = new ArrayInput(array(
            'command' => 'doctrine:schema:create',
        ));
        $command->run($input, new NullOutput());

        // get the Entity Manager
        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();

        // load fixtures
        $client = static::createClient();
        $loader = new \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataFixtures\ContainerAwareLoader($client->getContainer());
        $loader->loadFromDirectory(static::$kernel->locateResource('@IbwJobeetBundle/DataFixtures/ORM'));
        $purger = new \Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger($this->em);
        $executor = new \Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor($this->em, $purger);
        $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures());
    }

    public function testFunction()
    {
          // here you test save any object or test insert any object 
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        $this->em->close();
    }
}
```

like in this  Link : [Jobeet Unit Test Tutorial](http://www.intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/08/14/symfony2-jobeet-day-8-the-unit-tests/)
explain how to Test Entity and Entity Repository

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.